# How to have a dynamically sized CustomPainter in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, layout, widget, custom-painting, custom-painter

Consider the following code from the [Flutter docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html):

```
CustomPaint(
  painter: Sky(),
  child: const Center(
    child: Text(
      'Once upon a time...',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 40.0,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
        color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

I don't want a text widget.

I don't want the CustomPaint widget to be obscured by a child widget.

Also I want the CustomPaint widget to fill whatever space is available to it.

I presume the solution is to replace the Text widget with a BLANK widget like Expanded.

But, I've tried the Expanded, Container, Spacer, and Space widgets in various combinations but always either get an error or a zero size.

Thanks!

Comment: you want to set dynamic size according to your custom drawing? or cover up whole screen?

Comment: Thanks for your effort.  I updated the question.  Hopefully that explains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how you do it:

```
Expanded(
  child: CustomPaint(
    painter: MyCustomPainter(),
    size: Size.infinite,

  ),
),
```

Answer (score -3):

You can get height and width of the screen by using MediaQuery and use them

*Note : The people who are negative marking I respect their efforts and want to thank them but along with that I would like to request them that kindly read the entire post with patience that the question has been updated after date of answer as it's already negative I'm not gonna update it but hoping some humour with those kinds of people. thanks*

```
final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return CustomPaint(
      size: Size(width,height),
      painter: Sky(),
      child: const Center(
        child: Text(
          'Once upon a time...',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 40.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
            color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: That's only valid if your canvas fills the whole screen.